# Filter questions with no accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, questions, accepted-answer, filtering

I have some questions with answers, but none of the answers are acceptable (just wrong).

I'm sure there are a lot more people with the same problem.

Can you add a button to filter questions with answers but no accepted answer?

This way, people will see those questions and maybe try to offer a new perspective.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/search. You want `hasaccepted:0` in your search terms.

For example, here are all the SO questions with [sql](/questions/tagged/sql)  that have no accepted answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+hasaccepted%3A0

Comment: That is sorted by date (first results from 2008, I doubt that they will ever accept), Is there a way to reverse the sort ?

Comment: Never mind, if you use hasaccepted:0 in the "newest" tab it will do that.

Answer (score 5):

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered dos exactly that.

[image]

Comment: But it does not allow the user to (for example) find all the `ruby` tagged questions that have no accepted answer.

Comment: Yes it does. You can click on the tags on the right part of the screen to filter, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ruby

Comment: @Aleadam I stand corrected! It still doesn't give you the power search options the way that `hasaccepted:0` does, but it should get 90% of the people what they need.

Comment: @Phrogz we both learned something. I did not know about the options for /search

Comment: It shows questions with 0 answers... not questions with unaccepted answers

Comment: @Yochai, no it does not. See proof above

Comment: Ok, missed the smaller tabs. I was on "no answers" by default

Comment: That's still "no upvoted answers"

Comment: Isn't this only useful, if the list of tags happens to include the one you want?  If it doesn't you have to enter a manual search, which seems a bit odd, to me.