# Why isn't there a dedicated button for accessing questions with no accepted answer?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

There are a lot of times when I want to answer the questions that have not accepted answers. Why isn't there a simple way for doing so?

I know about searching "hasaccepted:0", but why isn't there a dedicated button like "Unanswered" on the top?

Edit: At least it may be a good idea to add a new tab to the unanswered page for the questions with no accepted answer.

Comment: What's wrong with that big "Unanswered" button on every site?

Comment: @Bobby: As far as I've checked, it only shows the questions with no answer at all, not the ones with "no accepted" answers. Also, I've read other questions about it (in meta) and everyone suggests searching. like this: [Filter Q's with no accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86460/filter-questions-with-no-accepted-answer)

Comment: No, it shows all unanswered questions, that includes questions with no accepted answer.

Comment: Ok. I get it. But what about adding a tab for these questions?

Comment: Also, please can anyone explain the reason for downvote? I thought this was a good feature to have, I've checked other questions,.... Because I wanna learn what to ask and how to ask it.

Comment: [The FAQ explains that one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). Votes are different down here.

Comment: @Bobby I didn't know about the voting difference. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, like Bobby says in the comments, the button exists. Have you tried the "Unanswered" button on every SE site? It exists in the Meta sites too.

It will show:

- Questions with no answers.
- Questions with answers but without an accepted one and, apparently, that *"[have no answers voted greater than zero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18870/176533)"*.

[image: Unanswered button]

Comment: Are you sure it shows the Q's with no accepted answers? Because whenever I try it, it just shows the Q's with "no answers".

Comment: @FlomEnol Yes it does. I'm sure of it. If you don't see them, it might be that there are more questions with no answers at all, but the other ones are listed too. If you keep scrolling you'll find them. :)

Comment: @FlomEnol On this site, click on "Unanswered", then choose the "Votes" tab. The 7th question has one answer and it's listed. :)

Comment: It may be so because of the amount of the questions with no answer. I just thought it may be a good feature to have for easier access. That's all. Also, there may be others to think this feature is needed, like [Filter Q's with no accepted answer]http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86460/filter-questions-with-no-accepted-answer.

Comment: Oh well, you'd like a different button? I'm not sure they're going to implement it, but that would be a different question, I guess.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I asked it poorly, but it should be asked as a "feature request", right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you want to ask it, that's the tag. :)

Comment: Actually, if any answer get voted up to at least 1, the system considers the question 'answered'. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18870).

Comment: @yhw42 Thanks, I'll add that!

Comment: @yhw42 I didn't know that. Thanks for mentioning it. It clarified some of my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If it bothers you, you could always make a bookmark to the [search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0) and add it as a button in your browser toolbar.

Of course, you'll need one per site, which could get a bit messy.

I'm not sure it's something the devs would care too much about, and I suspect you'll eventually get a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, it bothers me. Because sometimes I want to add an answer from a different point of view and also it may help the one asking to have people trying to give better answers and get accepted.